# The meaning of made out in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of "made out" in this sentence? 
"... for example, that I had made out a check on an overdrawn account , causing my husband to receive an embarrassing phone call at work from a bill Collecter "

Answer (score 1):

You could probably say that "made out" means "**written**" in that context-

> "I had **written** a check from an overdrawn account".

Definition from [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/make--out)

> **make out**
>
> a. to write out or complete, as a bill or check.

The implication is that you tried to pay a check from an overdrawn account, either way.